# how to get last event status in apache kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

In an event driven architecture, we are using Apache Kafka as a mean of persistence (no database available)

We have set up an Apache Kafka topic to publish the state of a certain event

As the event goes through different steps, its state changes; each one of these changes get published in the topic:

```
ID1:started
ID2:started
ID3:started
ID1:intermediate
```

...

In this scenario, how to get the last state of a certain ID?

Comment: Is your topic compacted? Are these ids the Kafka key?

Comment: I think it is not compacted, but if necesary I could create it compacted. Yes, those ID could be Kafka key

Comment: What you describe is one of the use cases of compacted topics as the latest key of a message will remove earlier identical keys after compaction. In code, this can be enabled by using a KTable or state store, I believe, but I'm not too familiar with Kafka Streams API

Comment: thank you, can you show me some KTable example code?

Comment: Like I said, I am not familiar with that API

Comment: Hi leccionesonline. You may find useful info here : https://www.confluent.io/blog/distributed-real-time-joins-and-aggregations-on-user-activity-events-using-kafka-streams/  The best way to implement it will depend on WHAT you want to do with the last state. The API describes a usecase : https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#table-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.streams.Consumed-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized- The key is is to materialize the KTable in a local store, which is queryable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consume your events as KTable to get the latest state for any given key.

Considering that in the below events :

ID1:started
ID2:started
ID3:started
ID1:intermediate

If kafka topic contains data in following format :

```
<ID1:started>
<ID2:started>
<ID3:started>
<ID1:intermediate>
```

where ID1, ID2 and so on.. are the keys and second part is status.

You can consume this topic as KTable :

```
KTable<String,String> statusTable = builder.table(TopicName);
```

And expected output will :

```
<ID1:intermediate>
```

In case if events have different key, you can change the keys using .map() operations.

You can refer concepts here : https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#creating-source-streams-from-kafka

For Consuming a topic as a table, refer the methods : https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#table-java.lang.String-

Comment: thank you Nishu, I was studying ktable api but I cant find a method to get such expected output, could you please post some exampl code?

Comment: If you consume topic as a KTable, it will automatically give you the latest state of all keys.  I have added link in the answer and Code snippet is already there :)

Comment: thank you Nishu. It turns out this solution only works if you have just one instance of one microservice, but now we have more microservices and instances... how would I do your solution scalable?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's where GlobalKTable are introducted. Difference between KTable and GlobalKTable is each partition/instance will have it's own Ktable while GlobalKTable will contain records from all instances. There are advantages as well as disadvantages of using GlobalKTable but that depends on your scenario.  You can see more on GlobalKTable : https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#globalktable

Comment: thank you Nishu. I have seen GlobalKTable are not very efficient... could you suggest a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for KTable example.

https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/kafka-streams-convert-to-ktable/confluent.html

I'm in search for answer myself. Looking for ways to get latest state of an event over a period of time.